# Error Creating Simple Controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, httpexception

I am creating a simple empty Controller `Default1` in ASP.NET MVC4 VS 2012 but when I run it, it gives error.

My Controller is as follows:

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default1/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

     }
```

Following Error is thrown:

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/Default1&#39; was not found or does not     implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext                 requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext,IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext,AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionSep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Actually I have been creating controllers before this event but some how what ever controller I creates now is not accessible.

Comment: Show the code you use to call the controller and show your controller as well.

Comment: Are you using areas by any chance?

Comment: &#39; is the culprit from where the controller is called

Comment: Can you remove that controller and add a new one "SampleController" and do compile?

Comment: I am calling simply in Browser http://localhost:27169/Default1

Comment: I have tried removing and adding controller with different name but same result

Comment: What does your RouteConfig look like?

Comment: Added RouteConfig in Original Post

Comment: have you check that in view folder Defaul1 Folder is exists or not ?

Answer (score -1):

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default1", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The controller is explicitly specified in the question - the asker is not trying to make `Default1` the default controller.

Comment: Hi,
His controller is `Default1` and he routes the controller is `Home` so his controller source is not found. that's why generate the error.

Comment: No, `Home` is the *default* controller - when the controller is *specified* (as in the question), the default controller is irrelevant.

Comment: The problem is not with default controller

Comment: My problem is that whatever controller i creates, throws following error. My idea is somehow Routes are not cofigured properly.